# How to send send message with emotion icon(smily faces) in android?

Tags: android, message

I am doing a small project which send message with emotion icons.i use following function that converts image to spannble string to send emotion icon as text but problem is that receiver is unable to see emotion icon on his message instead of emotion icon receiver sees [h]????

```
 public SpannableStringBuilder addSmily(int position){
        Drawable happySmileys = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(mThumbIds[position]);
        happySmileys .setBounds(0, 0, happySmileys.getIntrinsicWidth(), happySmileys.getIntrinsicHeight());
        /*Drawable sadSmiley = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_4);
        sadSmiley .setBounds(0, 0, sadSmiley.getIntrinsicWidth(), sadSmiley.getIntrinsicHeight());*/

        SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        builder.append("[h]");
        builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(happySmileys), builder.length()-"[h]".length(), builder.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        return builder;
    }
```

Thanks for reading my question. any suggestion ??

Comment: chrish images are not posssible to send with sms

Comment: Thanks @imran for quick response. but what the logic behind sending message with emotion icon??

Comment: send emotion code instead of drawable

Comment: see codes here http://www.mycell.com/shortcuts.htm

Comment: but i wan send emotion icon as gosmsPro app do. this app is using the feature. we can send stylish emotion icon from this app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Babibu for your concept. After some research, I found the solution 
here is how i implement.

my application send message for example "i am happy [image]"   as   "i am happy :-)" Then When i received the message i check for pattern :-) and i replace it with  [image].

here is how i replace

```
public static CharSequence addSmileySpans(Context context, CharSequence your_recieved_message) {
    HashMap<Integer, String> smilyRegexMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    smilyRegexMap.put(R.drawable.android_smile, ":-\\)");


    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(your_recieved_message);
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Iterator it = smilyRegexMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        Pattern mPattern = Pattern.compile((String) pairs.getValue(),
                Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = mPattern.matcher(your_recieved_message);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            Bitmap smiley = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    context.getResources(), ((Integer) pairs.getKey()));
            builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(smiley), matcher.start(),
                    matcher.end(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
    }
    return builder;
}
```

then set the return value of the function on your TextView something like

```
messageTextView.setText(addSmileySpans(context,"i iam happy :-)"))
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking to do is not support in all devices, the application that manage user phone messages don't know how to do it. If you wish to make it work you need to write your own application for reading messages(it's not that hard by the way). Then when you send a message to someone with your application installed, well you can do what ever...

Comment: i didn't get u @Babibu. further explanation will be appreciated. thanks in advance